# Soql query on products and accounts

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

Want to write an soql query on Accounts and products. If i select **Account** lookup in visualforce page i want to display history information of that account in table format. I tried to write an soql query where i am unable to get output please some one help me out.

Comment: Are the products you want to see somehow related to the accounts?

Answer (score 1):

On Account, if you use Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Fields -> Set History tracking you can nominate fields for which changes are recorded and query that data like this:

```
public AccountHistory[] history {
    get {
        return [
                select OldValue, NewValue, IsDeleted, Field,
                        CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
                from AccountHistory
                where AccountId = :accountId
                order by CreatedDate desc
                ];
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this history tracking mechanism is [not available for products](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMdAAK).